# HTML table with Sharepoint List Values

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, jquery-plugins, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I'm having trouble working with a severely locked down version of sharepoint. I am trying to render a graph based on a Sharepoint list and although i've had success displaying the chart in sharepoint using JQuery with a HTML table, the JQuery plugin I'm using will not render the sharepoint list out of the box.

The Microsoft table renders *horribly*. The list is simple but I need to add the values into a properly structured HTML table which will allow me to then extract the values from it using JavaScript.

Any suggestions as to how I could loop the list values into a 'proper' table which I could then manipulate with Javascript would be greatly appreciated.

Just so you're aware, I have no access to sharepoint designer or any back-end system and so any manipulation is limited to whatever I can run client side or in a custom web part.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach, but you could try getting your data using the [SPServices JQuery library](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex to get your data through web services.

You would get the list item data using the [GetListItems](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems&referringTitle=Lists) operation.

This approach would eliminate the need try parsing the SharePoint HTML tables. You can do this all through a Content Editor or Form web part.